# What organizations made more than 100 endorsements in US state and local judicial races between 2009 and 2018?

Tags: united-states, election, judiciary, local-government, endorsement

Other than bar associations and trade associations, what organizations made more than 100 endorsements in US state and local judicial races between 2009 and 2018?

Comment: This question is going to be very hard to answer as not all endorsements are easily searchable on the internet.

Comment: Good point, I changed it to >100. Does that seem like an improvement? Otherwise I can change it back.

Comment: I am not sure that makes it easier to find all the possible endorsements

Comment: Is there any way to make it clear that I don't require an exhaustive answer? This question is meant in the spirit similar to the following questions, each of which asks for an answer in the form of a potentially long list that is hard to check for completeness: [1](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32509/which-media-organizations-use-catch-and-kill), [2](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/who-was-on-brexits-side), [3](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48387/why-try-to-impeach-trump-now). Is there a way to make the wording match the intent?